# Image not updating on S3 bucket HTML page when requesting data from AWS API

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3

I have 2 boxes on an html page. X and Y. The user enters numbers clicks calculate and a image is supposed to appear. The problem is when I click calculate the image never updates with a image with new data on the plot (basically the image is not being updated). When I print the Image URL: on the bottom of the html page the url changes to the right image but its not displayed on the html page. If i copy the url into another tab it displays the image that should be displayed on the html page.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>API Calculator</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>API Calculator</h1>
    <form id="calculator-form">
        <label for="x">Enter value for x:</label>
        <input type="number" id="x" name="x" required>
        <br>
        <label for="y">Enter value for y:</label>
        <input type="number" id="y" name="y" required>
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
    </form>
    <div id="result">
        <img id="result-image" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/aerocastwx.com/image_requests/res_plot.png" alt="Result Image">

    </div>
    <div id="image-url">Image URL: </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const form = $('#calculator-form');
    const resultDiv = $('#result');
    const resultImage = $('#result-image');

    form.on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const x = $('#x').val();
        const y = $('#y').val();

        // Replace {} placeholders in the API URL with actual values
        const apiUrl = `https://xxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/september12stage/calculator?x=${x}&y=${y}`;

        $.ajax({
            url: apiUrl,
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
            console.log(data); // Check the response in the browser console
        
            if (data && data.ans !== undefined) {
                // Set the src attribute of the <img> element to display the image
                var resultImage = $('#result-image');
                resultImage.attr('src', data.ans); // Use data.ans as the image URL
                resultImage.show(); // Show the image
        
                // Update the Image URL div
                $('#image-url').text('Image URL: ' + data.ans);
            } else {
                console.error('Invalid API response:', data);
                resultDiv.html('Invalid API response');
                resultImage.hide(); // Hide the image container
            }
        },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data from the API:', error);
                resultDiv.html('Error fetching data from the API');
                resultImage.hide(); // Hide the image container in case of an error
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(data.ans)` to make sure it has an image url?

Comment: Yeah it has the image url

Comment: I tested your code locally using a different  `apiUrl`. Your code works fine. I can only assume CORS is not set up on your images. That would explain why you get the data back and can see the url but the image won't actually display. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cors.html) for use on AWS S3.